# mobile to main site redirect

Tags: wordpress, redirect, mobile, themes, wordpress-theming

[image: this is my mobile site screen-shot]
I want to switch my mobile site to main site. remember when you open facebook on mobile then view of facebook in mobile version is change and when you click on "Go to main site" then it appears main site in mobile. that i want.

And also main problem is both links are same means

```
main site url is  http://www.yousite.com
mobile site url is  http://www.yousite.com
```

when you open in mobile then mobile template is show and when i open is desktop then main site template is show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this on a previous version of my site and wrote about it here: http://arleym.com/mobile-device-detection-redirection/

Basically I have some device detection that will be ignored if there is a query string. So the "view desktop version" link will avoid the detection/redirection and give the user a cookie.

I used this detection script: http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/

and modified my switch like so:

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_GET['switch'])){
         setcookie('switch',$_GET['switch']); // set a cookie
    }
    if(!isset($_GET['switch']) && !isset($_COOKIE['switch'])){
         require_once('/server/path/arleym.com/mobile_device_detect.php'); //Andy Moore's script
         mobile_device_detect(true,false,true,true,true,true,true,'
         http://arley.me',false);
    }
?>
```

The view desktop url simply does its thing like href="http://whatever.com?switch=0"