# mobile-site to main-site and main-site to mobile-site

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, mobile, cookies

I done main-site and seperate mobile-site.

Main-site is *Wordpress*

Mobile-site is *HTML pages*

and I put following script for mobile auto redirect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    if (screen.width <= 769) {
        document.location = "http://mobile.mysite.com/";
    }
    //-->
</script>
```

But now I need **Full Site** link to main-site in mobile-site. By the above script, it's redirecting to same mobile-site.

I tried with *[cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471075/mobile-to-main-site-redirect)*. I dont know, why that not working properly.

Any-one help me. Thanks.

Comment: why are you checking screen width for detecting mobile devices ? You should use a php lib which will detect the device at server side and redirect the user to the corresponding link.

Comment: sounds good. first solve my problem, then we can do that.

Answer (score -1):

To redirect a mobile visitor you will need to determine if their browser is a web browser on a mobile device or not. You can determine which browser the visitor is using

If you are running a Content Management System (such as WordPress or Joomla), there may be plugins already available that help with handling mobile visitors.

Because mobile phones typically have a small screen width, you can redirect visitors to your mobile site if they have a screen width of less than or equal to 800 pixels. Place Javascript window.location code in the head section of your main website code. That way when your site is visited, the javascript will see the browser width and redirect to the appropriate site.

You can use a .htaccess redirect to transfer visitors based upon the MIME types the browser supports. For example, if the user's browser accepts mime types that include WML (Wireless Markup Language), then most likely it is a mobile device. The code below should be placed in your .htaccess file.

**Note:**

If you're using WordPress, try the Jetpack plugin. That comes with a free mobile version that you can enable. Anybody on a phone will see the mobile version automatically.

Main site to Mobile ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    if (screen.width <= 769) {
        document.location = "http://mobile.mainsite.com/";
    }
    //-->
</script>
```

Mobile to Main site ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    if (screen.width > 769) {
        document.location = "http://mainsite.com/";
    }
    //-->
</script>
```